# IE Can't Parse UTF-8

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, firefox, encoding

I have a file that is UTF-8 BOM encoded.  It has one character x9F (DEC 159) which is the 'Ÿ' character.  IE and Firefox both fail to parse this file.  The encoding element is encoding="UTF-8".  I read that some older browsers refuse to display x80 - x9F, but that is specific to HTML.  Any idea why IE and FF are tripping on this?

Comment: Going on a limb and saying that you shouldn't expect anything to work on IE in the first place.. ever..

Comment: which version(s) of IE (and Firefox) are you testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASCII characters are all below 128. Latin-1 has control codes, not characters at x80 - x9F, and likewise Unicode has control codes at code points U+0080 through U+009F. If you have the character U+009F in your text, that's wrong; it should be U+0178, &#376 ; . If you have the single byte x9F in your file, that's doubly wrong; characters larger than 127 must be encoded in UTF-8 to work.

Comment: It looks like a single x9F was the problem.  I edited my question - I didn't mean ASCII, I meant one byte.  I should have done my homework because I thought UTF-8 covered closer to 255 chars with a single byte, not just ASCII.

Answer (score -1):

It is actually a common issue

UTF-8 BOM should be supported by XML according to specs, but actually only a few parsers accept it. By your comment it seems that not even IE and Firefox, at least for the version you are using, do it.

What can you do? Nothing. It is just that those parsers are not good enough.